# How to split this string?

Tags: java, regex, string

How to split this string ?

```
String s="{hello.World::123}";
```

to Stirng array:

```
{"hello","World","123"}
```

using regex ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 String s ="{hello.World::123}";
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("[\\.:{}]+")));
```

**EDIT**:

Generalized solution:

```
 String s ="{hello.World::123}".replaceFirst("^[\\.:{}]+", " ").trim();
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("[\\.:{}]+")));
```

---

From the comments (@Peter Lawrey):

For the particular input,

```
 String s ="{hello.World::123}";
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.substring(1).split("[\\.:{}]+")));
```

Comment: @Emil, note that this solution will cause an empty string to be the first element in the array.

Comment: you can use `substring(1)` to skip the first character and avoid a blank field.

Comment: @Peter, In general, The split string can be more than one or may not present. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the inconvenience in my previous answer.

Here is something that may actually work:

```
String[] a = s.replaceAll("[\\{\\}]", "").split("\\.|::");
```

However, this will not allow you to have `{` or `}` as elements in  the *list*, but I guess you don't have that.

Comment: `\.` will throw a run time exception. Also note that `[::]` does not match a double colon, but just a single one (a character class always matches a single char! So `[::]` is the same as `[:]`).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that before I tested it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modifying John's solution to avoid empty string:

```
String s="{hello.World::123}";
s=s.substring(1, s.length()-1);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("[\\.:]+")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a simple, single split.  Your struggles might be telling you the same thing.

You can use regex to match on more than one word character and return each group, but I don't believe one call to split will do it.

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
s.split("\\.|::");
```